# Using Access for Sales Variance Reporting - Query issues

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I want to create a variance report.  `Simply sales - planned sales = variance` etc.

I have two table, one called `Actual` one called `Plan`.  Both have the same fields,

```
-account code
-month
-year
-sales
```

The idea being I populate the `Plan` table with the years plan data then update `Actuals` with actuals as they come in.

The problem I have, is how do I build a query that shows both (1) unplanned sales and (2) planned sales without an actual?  I can't find a join type that does it.

Or am I completely missing the point and a more obvious way of doing this?!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the problem. If sometimes records are missing in `Actual` and sometimes in `Plan` then combine a LEFT JOIN query with a RIGHT JOIN query in a UNION query.

```
SELECT
    P.*,
    A.sales - P.sales AS variance
FROM
    Plan P
    LEFT JOIN Actual A
        ON P.[account code] = A.[account code] AND
           P.month = A.month AND
           P.year = A.year
UNION ALL
SELECT
    A.*,
    NULL AS variance
FROM
    Plan P
    RIGHT JOIN Actual A
        ON P.[account code] = A.[account code] AND
           P.month = A.month AND
           P.year = A.year
WHERE
    P.[account code] IS NULL
```

The WHERE clause avoids duplicates and selects only records that were missing in the first SELECT query.

Comment: Thanks, this is great, but I don't think it is showing actual sales that were not in the planned sales?

Comment: The second SELECT (after UNION ALL) should do that. It shows records from A where there are no corresponding records in P.